# Chrome screen audio capture won't work on Mac

Tags: google-chrome-extension, recordrtc

I'm building a chrome extension that captures mic + screen + screen audio with recordrtc.

Everything is working on Windows, but it seems recording screen audio is not allowed on Mac.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, try checking the logs if there were any issues in Mac. Also, you can post this in the [chromium bug](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/?token=HVeKOXA6N_2oHg6zFFzqRToxNTI1NjkwOTY1&role=&continue=https%3A//bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry.do) to get any official statement from them.

Comment: Matt Hough, if you want to submit a bug on chromium, please write something like this: "canRequestAudioTrack" is never returned on Mac. Either it is always FALSY or never returned. This happens only on Mac. Windows is working fine. Ask chromium team to check this API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture